# Finding the Characteristic Function for the Supremum of a OU Process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, fourier-analysis, supremum-and-infimum, finance

I'm currently writing my BSc thesis on Lookback Option pricing under Ornstein Uhlenbeck Processes. I'm using the COS method for this. For this I need to find the fourier transform of the pdf (characteristic function) of the supremum of a OU process. I have tried to find articles on this but to no avail. Does anyone perhaps know of any articles describing ehat im looking for? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: An OU process can be written as an exponential plus a brownian motion at an exponential time. The supremum of a brownian motion is a folded normal law. Maybe theses two fact could help you. Or alternatively a Google research gave that : https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://hal.science/hal-01935756/file/Joint_law_OU_sup.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiKyIWL_b3-AhVhUqQEHUhnDk4QFnoECA8QAQ&usg=AOvVaw2byPCqVRkFMupxvdehR55p.

Comment: @jvc, thanks a lot. i indeed had found that paper aswell, but could'nt make sense of it unfortunately... But i do think that the first thing you mentioned, rewriting it as an exponential + BM will be helpful. Thanks for replying!!